# OpenSSL: How to create a certificate with an empty subject DN?

Tags: openssl, x509

Is it possible to create a PKCS#10 certificate request / X.509 certificate with the identifying information only in the subject alternate name attribute/extension? According to [X.509 4.1.2.6 Subject](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6), the subject can be empty for a certificate whose subject is not a CA as long as the subjectAltName is critical.

But when I use this config file with an empty distinguished_name section:

```
# request.config
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]

[ v3_req ]
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName=critical,email:certtest@example.com
```

and commands

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem -config request.config
```

OpenSSL complains:

```
error, no objects specified in config file
problems making Certificate Request
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

### test-no-cn.cnf file

```
[req] 
default_bits       = 4096
encrypt_key        = no
default_md         = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]

[ v3_req ]
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName=critical,email:certtest@example.com,URI:http://example.com/,IP:192.168.7.1,dirName:dir_sect

[dir_sect]
C=DK
O=My Example Organization
OU=My Example Unit
CN=My Example Name
```

### Generate the CSR

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -config test-no-cn.cnf -subj "/" -outform pem -out test-no-cn.csr -keyout test-no-cn.key
```

### Sign the CSR

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in test-no-cn.csr -signkey test-no-cn.key -out test-no-cn.crt -outform der -extensions v3_req -extfile test-no-cn.cnf
```

### View the resulting certificate

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in test-no-cn.crt -noout -text
```

Answer (score 11):

I also ran into this "no objects specified" error.  It was displaying a prompt like this for various fields:

`US []:`

And I was just pressing enter because I had already set these values in the .cnf file.  It turns out I needed to type all the values again, and then it worked.

Comment: I had to do the same. Despite putting values in the config file, it still prompted me for all the DN components again. I had to repeat them, but it worked at least.

Comment: This is because the config file did not actually contain default values. `C = US` means that the "prompt" for C is "US", not the default value. Instead, the file should contain `C = Country` and `C_default = US`.

Comment: Oh, and that's only if `prompt = yes [or blank]`. If `prompt = no` then `C = US` would mean "US" is the default value.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with `prompt = no` in the original config. That makes `openssl req` assume you intend to specify subject entries in the config file and hits a [preliminary check in req.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0e/apps/req.c#L1007-L1011).

There's a workaround: Remove `prompt = no`, and instead add `-subj /` to your `openssl req` command line. Here's an example script that produces both a CSR and a self-signed certificate:

```
cat > openssl.cnf <<EOF
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]

[ v3_req ]
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName=critical,email:certtest@example.com
EOF
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -config openssl.cnf -nodes -new -subj "/" \
  -out req.csr
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -config openssl.cnf -nodes -new -subj "/" \
  -x509 -out cert.crt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try "commonName = optional" in policy sections in openssl configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you enter any single one value from '"distinguished_name" group from your keyboard and it works fine...I mean you do not need to enter other values and can use their default(as mentioned in openssl.conf file)
that said

```
[ req ]
...
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
...

Should work fine.
```